# f.readline versus f.read print output

Tags: python, parsing, readfile

I am new to Python (using Python 3.6). I have a read.txt file containing information about a firm. The file starts with different report characteristics

```
CONFORMED PERIOD REPORT:             20120928 #this is 1 line
DATE OF REPORT:                      20121128 #this is another line

and then starts all the text about the firm..... #lots of lines here
```

I am trying to extract both dates (['20120928','20121128']) as well as some strings that are in the text (i.e. if the string exists, then I want a '1'). Ultimately, I want a vector giving me both dates + the 1s and 0s of different strings, that is, something like: ['20120928','20121128','1','0']. My code is the following:

```
exemptions = [] #vector I want

with open('read.txt', 'r') as f:
    line2 = f.read()  # read the txt file
    for line in f:
        if "CONFORMED PERIOD REPORT" in line:
            exemptions.append(line.strip('\n').replace("CONFORMED PERIOD REPORT:\t", ""))  # add line without stating CONFORMED PERIOD REPORT, just with the date)
        elif "DATE OF REPORT" in line:
            exemptions.append(line.rstrip('\n').replace("DATE OF REPORT:\t", "")) # idem above

    var1 = re.findall("string1", line2, re.I)  # find string1 in line2, case-insensitive
    if len(var1) > 0:  # if the string appears, it will have length>0
        exemptions.append('1')
    else:
        exemptions.append('0')
    var2 = re.findall("string2", line2, re.I)
    if len(var2) > 0:
        exemptions.append('1')
    else:
        exemptions.append('0')

print(exemptions)
```

If I run this code, I obtain ['1','0'], omitting the dates and giving correct reads of the file, var1 exists (ok '1') and var2 does not (ok '0'). What I don't understand is why it doesn't report the dates. Importantly, when I change line2 to "line2=f.readline()", then I obtain ['20120928','20121128','0','0']. Ok with the dates now, but I know that var1 exists, it seems it doesn't read the rest of the file? If I omit "line2=f.read()", it spits out a vector of 0s for each line, except for my desired output. How can I omit these 0s?

My desired output would be: ['20120928','20121128','1','0']

Sorry for bothering. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I went through it was finally the following:

```
exemptions = [] #vector I want

with open('read.txt', 'r') as f:
    line2 = "" # create an empty string variable out of the "for line" loop
    for line in f:
        line2 = line2 + line #append each line to the above created empty string
        if "CONFORMED PERIOD REPORT" in line:
            exemptions.append(line.strip('\n').replace("CONFORMED PERIOD REPORT:\t", ""))  # add line without stating CONFORMED PERIOD REPORT, just with the date)
        elif "DATE OF REPORT" in line:
            exemptions.append(line.rstrip('\n').replace("DATE OF REPORT:\t", "")) # idem above

    var1 = re.findall("string1", line2, re.I)  # find string1 in line2, case-insensitive
    if len(var1) > 0:  # if the string appears, it will have length>0
        exemptions.append('1')
    else:
        exemptions.append('0')
    var2 = re.findall("string2", line2, re.I)
    if len(var2) > 0:
        exemptions.append('1')
    else:
        exemptions.append('0')

print(exemptions)
```

So far this is what I got. It worked for me, although I guess working with beautifulsoup would increase the efficiency of the code. Next step :)

Answer (score 3):

The line `f.read()` will read the entire file into the variable `line2`. If you want to read line by line you could skip the `f.read()` all together and just iterate like so

```
with open('read.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
```

Otherwise as written, after you `.read()` into `line2` there is no more text to read out of `f` as it is all contained in the `line2` variable.

Comment: would be better to use f.readlines() and then for line in lines than splitting by \n as that might not give you the results you expect.

Comment: I'm not sure the first code snippet is even worth mentioning as a suggestion, the 2nd way is clearly the way to go

Comment: Thank you all. I totally understand your point. However, when I omit "line2=f..read()" from the original code, I obtain lots of 0s in the "exemptions" vector. I edited my original post with this information. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to "skip" two lines then before your for loop, you can add `f.readline()` twice to "pop" two lines before reading the rest.

Comment: I don't if I'm following. It's not about skipping two lines. By dropping the "line2=f.read()" from the original code, I obtain something like ['20120928','20121128','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0', and several thousands 0s more]. It seems it gives a 0 for every line in the "read.txt" file, which is not what I look for...

Answer (score 0):

`line2 = f.read()` reads *entire* file into `line2`, so there's nothing left to read for your `for line in f:` loop.